# Include Additional/Joined Data in Grid Column

Tags: module, magento-1, grid, column

I've got a Module that allows someone to add products to a warehouse. In the products listing under the warehouse, I've got the product_id, stock etc.

What I would like is for the product_id to be represented by the SKU and the name instead as the product_id doesn't give anyone much.

```
/**
 * Override of the Prepare Collection method on the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 * Defines the collection for the data within the grid
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 * @author Dan Hanly
 **/
public function _prepareCollection()
{
    if (!$this->_model) {
        $this->setModel(Mage::getModel('inventorymanagement/warehouse_product'));
    }

    // Override the Collection for the Class
    $collection = $this->_model->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    // Return the Completed Grid
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

/**
 * Override of the Prepare Columns method on the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 * Defines the columns for the grid
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 * @author Dan Hanly
 **/
public function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('product_id', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Product'),
        'index' => 'product_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('stock', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Current Stock'),
        'index' => 'stock'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('low_level', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Low Level Notification'),
        'index' => 'low_level'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('critical_level', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Critical Level Notification'),
        'index' => 'critical_level'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Above is what I have so far, and I have a feeling that it's either going to be done in the prepareCollection method or the prepareColumns one.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan
Just the below code at  **_prepareCollection()** function

```
$collection = $this->_model->getCollection();
```

After

```
   $proname = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('name');
   //modify here
    $product = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('product' => $proname->getBackend()->getTable()),
        'product.entity_id = main_table.product_id
        AND product.attribute_id = '.(int) $proname->getAttributeId().'',
        array('product_name'=>'value')
        )
    ->joinLeft(
        array('skutable' => $product->getEntityTable()),
        'skutable.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
        array(
            'product_sku' => 'skutable.sku',
        ));
```

And
 add below code for show  this two columns at  **__prepareColumns()**

```
$this->addColumn('product_name', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('subscribe')->__('Product Name'),
    'align' =>'left',
    'index' => 'product_name',
    'filter_index' =>'product.value'
  ));

  $this->addColumn('product_sku', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('subscribe')->__('Product Sku'),
    'align' =>'left',
    'index' => 'product_sku',
    'filter_index' =>'skutable.sku'
  ));
```

Comment: This gives me a ` Call to undefined method CompanyName_InventoryManagement_Model_Resource_Warehouse_Product_Collection::joinLeft()`

Comment: change $collection = $this->_model->getCollection(); to  $collection = Mage::getModel('inventorymanagement/warehouse_product')

Comment: hey try to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369497/magento-grid-sortering-and-filtering-works-incorrectly-after-joining-flat-tabl

Comment: I've used `->getSelect()` before the joins and now it's working fine. However, for the SKU, i'm getting a `1054 Unknown column 'skutable.attribute_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: For reference, the product name is being outputted flawlessly. :)

Comment: ok. my good... what is doing myself....so silly mistake by me.Thanks to

Comment: The SKU still doesn't work. The product name is fine, but the SKU gives me the above error

Comment: ok.let me check

Comment: Hi check here.now it works